# Priorities set on thread has no effect when start is called on the thread object

Tags: java, multithreading

I executed below code :

```
public class TestMain extends Thread{

    public static Runnable getRunnableObject(){
        Runnable r = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("inside runnable");
            }
        };

        return r;           
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread t2 = new Thread(getRunnableObject());
    //  t2.start();
        System.out.println("name "+t2.getName()+" id "+t2.getPriority()+" class "+t2.getClass()
                +" priortity "+t2.getPriority()+" state "+t2.getState()+" alive/dead "+t2.isAlive());

        System.out.println("runtime"+Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        t2.setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);
        System.out.println(t2.getPriority());

        t2.setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
        System.out.println(t2.getPriority());

        t2.setPriority(NORM_PRIORITY);
        System.out.println(t2.getPriority());
    }
}
```

Output :

```
name Thread-0 id 5 class class java.lang.Thread priortity 5 state NEW alive/dead false
runtime4
10
1
5
```

Now I run it once again uncommenting the code at line 22.

output 2 :

```
inside runnable
name Thread-0 id 5 class class java.lang.Thread priortity 5 state RUNNABLE alive/dead true
runtime4
5
5
5
```

Can you tell me why setting the priority is not working when I called start() on the thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a race condition.

By the time you're trying to set the priority of `t2`, it's already dead.
If you change your `Runnable` to block for a while, like this:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("inside runnable");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           //
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'll get the same sequence of 10, 1, 5.

Comment: Ah.. I get it. I also tried printing the state between setting the priorities and the state was printed as "NEW".